# Mongoose updates : Increment a counter and reset to 0 on a new date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
var Counter = new Schema ({
 _id: ObjectId,
 date: Date,
 counter: Number
})
```

On the request, I send date of a day and expect the date to be added and the counter to increase. Now when I add, a counter gets incremented ie 1,2,3 etc and a date gets added.

**Now here is a problem:** I want a counter to reset to 0 when a different date is given,(such to say on every new day, the counter should start at 0) and then start a counter increment again etc...

This is my code on how I have tried:

```
Counter.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 
   $set:{
     "date: thedate",
   },
   $inc: {
     "counter: counter+1"
    }
)
```

How do I achieve this ?

**UPDATE FOR MORE CLARIFIATION**

Take this example of two documents

```
{ 
  "_id": ObjectId("1111"), 
  "date": "2020-04-13", 
  "counter": 0, 
}

{ 
  "_id": ObjectId("2222"), 
  "date": "2020-04-29", 
  "counter": 0, 
}
```

My collection has more than one document. I want to update the document based on its id. For this case i want to update the 1st document of id 1111

Now if give an input date, say 2020-04-13 and id of '1111' which matches the first document, it should increment the couter to 1. If I give an the same date again (with same id of 111) it should increment the counter to 2.

If again I give an input date of 2020-04-14(which is another date) on the same first document of id 1111 it should reset the counter to 0.

Now How do I achieve this?

Comment: what Mongo version are you on?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I'm using Mongodb v4.0.5 and Mongoose 5.8.11

Comment: @Amani : what is the filter in your query which identifies the doc to be updated ? Try to upgrade your MongoDB version if possible to `4.2` cause this can be easily done on it.

Comment: @whoami I've changed from my local mongodb to Mongodb Atlas. I'm now using Mongodb Atlas with MO cluster..
 and from their documentation they say "Clusters on tiers M0, M2, and M5 only support MongoDB 4.2." => link https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/cluster-config/mongodb-version/
So I'm now on 4.2 version

Comment: @whoami the filter is the mongodb _id: ie 
Counter.findOneAndUpdate( { "_id": data.bizId})

Comment: Error itself says it can't accept an array ! So to which element in `products` array do you want to add value 2 ? To all elements or a certain element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can execute [update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) in `.update()` operations starting MongoDB version >= `4.2`, try below querie :

```
Counter.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: ObjectId("............") }, // filter query - Input of type ObjectId()
    /** Update date field with input & re-create 'counter' field based on condition */
    [{
      $addFields: {
        date: inputDate, // Input type of date, In general Date is saved in MongoDB as ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
        counter: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$date", inputDate ] }, { $add: [ "$counter", 1 ] }, 0 ] }
      }
    }]
  )
```

**Test :** Test aggregation pipeline here : [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7czhZ3bx0Ws)

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED MY QUESTION. Please see it.

I just want to update a single document based on its _id, that is to say, it is a single document(row) and not many documents.. So I don't want to use UpdateMany. Is there a way to use findOneAndUpdate (or just Update) for this single document? Can you modify your answer based on this recomendation? @ whoami

Comment: @Amani : yes updated but in general even using updateMany doesn’t cause any issue..

Comment: Your solution works pretty good. But I have a problem with my code logic. I have updated the question as well to include that code and its explanation. Please see it and help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Amani : You actual question is solved with this answer ! Please do not edit question with new issues !! We are not here to solve each & every code issue, You need to close this question & raise a new one rather-than making this question look messy with new issues !

Comment: Got it. I have accepted the answer. Your solution worked!

Comment: @Amani : I just meant to say usual things on SOF, So check my comments to your issue in this question or the other question you've raised  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear what you want to achieve but you can try this method by breaking the find and update

```
Counter.findOne({})  //match inside {} condition
.then(counter => {
   if(counter.date){ //apply date condition here
      counter.counter+=1;
      } else {
       counter.counter = 0;
      }
  counter.save()
   .then(updatedCounter => {
     // further action you want to take
   })
})
.catch(err => {
 //handle err here
})
```

Comment: I just want to increment a counter when the date i give in my request equals the already present date in the db and reset to 0 when the dates differ.

The code you gave above Don't work.. It just gives an error @harshit kohli

Comment: have you made the required changes because i've just provided you the method not the complete working code if you want i can write complete working code as well

Comment: I have accepted the answer above which was answered by another user. It worked for my case. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$inc` operator in MongoDB [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

Example:

```
export async function incrementCounter(db, formId) {
    return db.collection('posts').updateOne(
        { _id: postId },
        {
            $inc: {
                comments: 1 // Increments by 1. Similarly, -2 will decrement by 2.
            }
        }
    )
}
```

For the reset functionality, you can use MongoDB [Atlas Triggers](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/trigger-types/). You can also use a third-party library like [mongodb-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-cron).